# Want to store the imagepath

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to make an app where the registered user has to upload a profile pic.
After that, when the user logs in along with his other credentials the image of the user should also get displayed. I also want to pass the path of the image to the table in MySql. My image is stored ina folder in the server while the user details are stored in the table in the MySql. So when the user Logins along with the credentials the image should also get displayed. But when I'm tryin to register I'm getting an error and the image is not getting uploaded. And my app is getting crashed.

PHP file:

```
<?php

  $con=mysqli_connect("mysql8.000webhost.com","a6391170_root","root123","a6391170_sanjay");

  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $age = $_POST["age"];
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];
  $name1=$_POST["name1"];


  $imagepath="pictures1/" . $name1 . ".JPG";

  $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `user1` (name, age, username, password,name1,imagepath) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sissss", $name, $age, $username, $password,$name1,$imagepath);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

  mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

  mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

JAVA FILE:

```
           UploadImage ui=new UploadImage(image,etName1.getText().toString());
            ui.execute();
            User user = new User(name, age, username, password,name1);
            registerUser(user);
            break;


        case R.id.upImage:
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_IMAGE);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selecting Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RESULT_IMAGE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        Uri selectedImage=data.getData();
        imageUp.setImageURI(selectedImage);


        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        // Get the cursor
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();







        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }


private class  UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    Bitmap image;
    String name1;



    public UploadImage(Bitmap image, String name1)
    {

        this.image=image;
        this.name1=name1;

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected  Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
    System.out.println("here"); 
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
        String encodedImage= Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",encodedImage));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1",name1));



        HttpParams httpRequestParams=getHttpRequestParams();
        HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post=new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "upload.php");



        try
        {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

}

```
private HttpParams  getHttpRequestParams()
{


    HttpParams httpRequestParams=new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,1000*30);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,1000*30);
    return httpRequestParams;
}
```

Comment: you dont have to store the image path in mysql, just store the image name and make sure you always upload the files to one particular folder in your server

Comment: Then how can i retrieve that particular image for that particular user ?

Comment: you may want to take your database connection details out of the question.

Comment: store the image name on database. suppose u upload images in ti user_images folder, while fectching user_images/image name.png

Comment: @Niranjan hi.. ive saved the image name in the mysql table and the image in the folder in a server then how im supposed to fetch it .. can you please tell me what chages should i make in the php file ?

Comment: @swapsaraf <img src="path to you image folder/image name from database">

Comment: how to do it in java

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
    <?
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql8.000webhost.com","a6391170_root","root123","a6391170_sanjay");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$UploadedFileName=$_FILES['name1']['name'];
if($UploadedFileName!='')
{
                $upload_directory = "pictures1/";
                $imagepath=$upload_directory.$UploadedFileName;
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['name1']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory.$UploadedFileName))
                {    
                     $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `user1`(name, age, username, password,name1,imagepath) 
                            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");
                     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sissss", $name, $age, $username, $password,$UploadedFileName,$imagepath);
                     mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
                     mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
                }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: So what changes will i have to make in java file ?

Comment: just copy this where you wrote these things, i don't think.. you need to change any thing.. i just edited.. just copy it and paste.. @swapsaraf

Comment: i changed my php file .. now when i register nothing is happening.. the app just keeps on running .. in the sense its not going on the next activity

Comment: if(move_uploaded_file){ // You have to write your query here.}@swapsaraf

Comment: im getting confused.. can you  please edit in the cose .. it would be of great help

Comment: why u used mysqli_stmt_bind_param() @swapsaraf

Comment: to bind the variabled.. whats the alternative ?

Comment: Now, check the edited answer. Use it. Don't be confuse. just because of me.. if  you are getting confused.. then i'm sorry. i'm embarassed @swapsaraf

Comment: hey not to feel embarrased.. infact youre helping me out :D :)

Comment: should i change the column name to UploadedFileName?

Comment: No no. That is not the problem. What error u R getting now.? @swapsaraf

Comment: Sorry @swapsaraf. I did my best. Guilty for not getting your answer.

Comment: No problem mate..  just wanted to know i retrieve the image with its name ?

Comment: yes. Retrieve the image with the name stored in table.. because.. that image is stored in the folder with that name only @swapsaraf

Comment: so its ok if i dont store the path of the image right ? then what changes would i have to make in java as well as php file ?

Comment: See @swapsaraf I'm sorry man. I don't know Java, i mean i never worked on java.. so can't say..